# curl (60) unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: unix, ssl, curl

I'm trying to connect to the OneDrive API (https://api.onedrive.com) using curl, but it throws me

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

The page opens in Firefox without a certificate warning. I checked the certificate info, put all three certificates (Baltimore CyberTrust Root, Microsoft IT SSL SHA2 and storage.live.com) into /usr/share/ca-certificates and installed them using

```
dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates
```

However, I keep getting this error. Any ideas?

```
me@host:~$ curl -vi https://api.onedrive.com
* Rebuilt URL to: https://api.onedrive.com/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 134.170.109.152...
* Connected to api.onedrive.com (134.170.109.152) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs/
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Server hello (2):
* SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
* Closing connection 0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.

me@host:~$ curl -V
curl 7.38.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.38.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1k zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.29 libssh2/1.4.3 librtmp/2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp scp sftp smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS IDN IPv6 Largefile GSS-API SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP
```

Comment: What certificates you get? Maybe you are behind some SSL intercepting device so you need different certificates than the original? And what version of curl you are using: add output from `curl -V` to your question.

Comment: Added `curl -V`. No proxy etc - just a simple home router. Other https sites I tried work.